# calling get_target_property() on target that is defined later

Tags: cmake

I have a problem with CMake `get_target_property`. It runs on a library that is defined later and returns an error. This is my code:

```
add_library(UT_pal_logger OBJECT ${SOURCES})
target_add_interfaces(UT_pal_logger cppunit_addon)
```

In other files there is:

```
function(target_add_interfaces TARGET OTHER_TARGETS)
   foreach(OTHER_TARGET ${OTHER_TARGETS})
      get_target_property(TMP_INCLUDES ${OTHER_TARGET} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
      if(TMP_INCLUDES)
         target_include_directories(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${TMP_INCLUDES})
      endif()
   endforeach(OTHER_TARGET)
endfunction()
```

and:

```
add_library(cppunit_addon STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(cppunit_addon PUBLIC Include)
```

Note that `cppunit_addon` brings some headers that are used in `UT_pal_logger`.

This fails with the message:

```
CMake Error at Scripts/CMake/target_add_interfaces.cmake:22 (get_target_property):
  get_target_property() called with non-existent target "cppunit_addon".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  .../logger/CMakeLists.txt:36 (target_add_interfaces)
```

However this configures and builds just fine:

```
add_library(UT_pal_logger STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(UT_pal_logger cppunit_addon)
```

---> `target_link_libraries` somehow wait until everything is parsed and `get_target_property` does not. This is also [documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/get_target_property.html):

> This command can get properties for any target **so far** created.

I could also change the order of `add_directory` commands to fix this. But this is not a clean solution. How can i make `get_target_property` wait until everything was parsed?

Comment: Normally any include dependency also requires a link dependency. So I admit that I don't understand what you are trying to achieve you `target_add_interfaces()` function? If you have a link dependency your problem is solved (public include directories are propagated automatically).

Comment: @Florian, he is trying to add include directories for *OBJECT* library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831517/cmake-add-interfaces-but-do-not-link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) if you want CMake to evaluate your property at generation time and not during configuration time.

If successfully tested the following code snippet:

```perl
add_library(UT_pal_logger OBJECT ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(
    UT_pal_logger 
    PUBLIC "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:cppunit_addon,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of CMake also support `target_link_libraries` on (or off) `OBJECT` libs.

```
add_library(UT_pal_logger OBJECT ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(UT_pal_logger PUBLIC cppunit_addon)
target_link_libraries(other PUBLIC UT_pal_logger) # ands objects and links cppunit_addon
```

These are separate features availible from CMake 3.14.